# Getting Child and Grand Children records Query

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits, class, query

I would like to get all the records related to a parent which includes the children, grandchildren, great grandchildren etc. What is the best way of writing such a query?
The end goal is, I am trying to get the values down the hierarchy and roll it up to the parent account.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this.  You can easily get the children... but below that gets more difficult.  I would advise doing a query for all of the children and mapping them to the parent.  From there, keep doing queries on the children of that, and while there are results pass into the associated map.  Sort of a confusing explanation but I can't think of a clearer way to say it.  I will show my example under the assumption you are using a Standard Contact controller and extension (It gets more complicated if you are trying to do this bulkified in a trigger.  You would need to do a similar situation, but place values into maps so that you aren't running too many queries to hit limits):

```
Contact parent = (Contact)controller.getRecord();
List<Contact> spawns = new List<Contact>();
spawns.add(parent);//Remove this line if you don't want the original one included
List<Contact> nextInLine = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE ContactId = :parent.Id];
while (!nextInLine.isEmpty())
{
  for (Contact child: nextInLine)
  {
    spawns.add(child);
  }
  nextInLine = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE ContactId IN :nextInLine];
}
```